# Background resizing in Edge and IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I was upgrading our WordPress website with a background image, which you can see on the link: http://www.financnitrgi.com/

The background resizes great in Chrome, Opera and Firefox, but in IE and Edge it is another story. When the site loads in IE/Edge the background is OK, but when resizing the browser window the the background starts shifting under the text of the website, which is not what it should do.

Does anybody have any experience with this kind of problem?

The code that I used for the background:

```
div.content{
background: url(http://www.financnitrgi.com/wp-content/uploads/bankakoper.jpg) center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: auto 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can reproduce the problem. The website looks the same here across browsers, and I can see problems, but the same problems are visible in all browsers and they don't start only on resizing.

Comment: But if you only check the background image and compare it to the behaviour in various browsers (i.e. Chrome vs Edge or Internet Explorer) there is a big difference. In the Explorer the background goes under the text, in Chrome it does not. This is the specific problem that i am looking at.

Comment: I don't see it, sorry. like I said, I see the problems, but they're the same problems in different browsers. Can you put up some screenshots of the differences you see?

Answer (score 1):

you have some markup errors that different browsers may correct/compensate for differently.... for IE first go Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages".. save changes.

Now open IE at the site. Press f12 to display the dev tool, select the Console tab, it should show the following errors/warnings

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
www.financnitrgi.com

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
HTML1512: Unmatched end tag.

www.financnitrgi.com (393,2)
HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.
www.financnitrgi.com (396,2)

HTML1509: Unmatched end tag.
www.financnitrgi.com (1355,90)

HTML1523: Overlapping end tag. 
www.financnitrgi.com (1798,75)

see also the validator results here [w3c validation](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A//www.financnitrgi.com/)

Correct these errors ....

The background resizing problem ONLY occurs when IE's ActiveX Filtering is turned OFF....
Tools>ActiveX Filtering to turn YOUR IE ActiveX Filtering on..... this stops flash (which is an ActiveX control in MSIE browsers) from loading...

When IE's AX filtering is turned on your website uses fallback img elements, which don't have the background problem...the conclusion would be that the flash object is sized incorrectly. USE css height and width instead of the presentation attributes... (depending, the w3c validators will pick this up to alert you to use css for sizing of elements instead of presentation attributes)

To debug your css problem, use the find tool in the dev tool's DOM Explorer tab to select the `<object>` element that hosts the flash content....

Include in your browsing testing

1. test in the browsers' NoAddons mode.
2. for IE11 - test with ActiveX Filtering enabled/disabled and
3. for IE11 - test with Tracking Protection enabled/disabled

Whenever flash or script content is blocked by ActiveX Filtering or Tracking Protection, a blue circle with a line through it will appear in the IE Address bar, double click it to toggle your AX and TP preferences for the current web site..... If you have "Always record developer console messages" turn on... the IE dev tool's Console will list the scripts and activeX content that is being blocked.